# Does mentioning that I had two US tourist visa refusals is negative for my UK skilled worker visa application?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom

In September/2013 I applied for a US tourist visa because I was going to stay 16 months in Canada as a student, and I was 19 years old, had no job, no properties, nothing haha and in the US visa interview I mentioned that I was going to stay in an American friend's (who is a girl, and I am a dude) house. The immigration did not take it well and refused my application.

However, when I was in Canada I applied again and got it refused again, since the immigration agent had my records and asked if I knew anyone from America and I said yes (if I have said no the consequences would probably be worse because it could have been interpreted as a lie).

Anyway... almost 9 years later I have a degree, doing my Masters, have bought an apartment here in Brazil (I'm Brazilian by the way), and I have just been offered a job offer in the UK! Amazing!! :)

However these two US visa situations are hauting my :chuckles: since that in the UK visa skilled worker form, they ask you if you ever had any immigration problem (visa refusals to anywhere in the world are included).

Then, should I describe both situations and write that I have two US visa applications refused due to lack of funds and ties to my home country (Brazil) by that time? Will it have a negative impact in my UK Skilled Worker visa application? Or... should I just select "No" and carry on with the application?

Also, just for the records, I am in a Civil Partnership and my civil partner is now applying with me, as my dependent :)

Thank you so much,

Comment: Lying is basically how you get banned for life from the UK (your application won't be even reviewed at all for ten years).

Comment: FWIW the UK and US do share (or have the ability to request from the other) certain immigration data.

Comment: I see... But mentioning these two US visa refusals will have a negative impact in my UK skilled worker application?

Comment: You should assume that the UK can access this US information. It's clear that the US and the UK share immigration information under the Fives Eyes Treaty; see [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83130/do-embassies-know-about-visa-refusal-in-other-countries/83137#83137) and [that](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/147441/will-a-us-visa-refusal-affect-my-uk-visa-application/147442?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C0.0000#147442).

Comment: @user3081005 Certainly it's a negative input. But none of us (nor you) can know if the the other circumstances and showings of your UK application are strong enough for a new UK application to be granted. The only way to know is to file the application. The points raised here, however, are clear that misrepresenting your history is a slam-dunk to earn you a UK ban.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica How is it a negative input?

Comment: @MJeffryes The UK twice found the OP unqualified for a visa. Countries ask about visa refusals because refusals suggest that the applicant is unqualified. This is a suggestion or a whiff, not an automatic refusal. OTOH, the current application is for working and moving long-term, which (as you correctly point out in your answer), is a different kettle of fish and previous refusals for travel are not directly relevant to his new application.

Comment: No need to mention that the visa was was refused "due to lack of funds and ties to your home country", this is just your assumption (doesn't matter if it's true). Just mention that the visa was refused, that's it, or at the maximum, the official reason, "refused under section 214(b)" (which seems to be from your question). Just provide brief and accurate information. It shouldn't affect skilled worker visa. That is a very different category of visa, and your situation is different now.

Comment: I'd be surprised if an unemployed 19 y/o with nothing to his name would *succeed* in getting a visa to the US. That doesn't bar you from succeeding in building your career later in life. Just tell them that you were naive and applied for a US visa as a kid and got denied, and move on. Nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 6):

It depends what the refusals were for. In your case, you were refused a US visit visa for not having sufficient ties to your home country–this is also a common reason for UK visit visas to be refused. But this refusal reason is totally irrelevant to a long term UK visa–you don't need to prove you'll go back to your home country for such a visa.

The decision making process for skilled worker visas does not depend on the discretion of the decision maker. There is nowhere in the decision making process where a US visa refusal on the basis of lack of ties outside the US could lead to a skilled worker visa being refused *unless* you happen to lie about it. Lying on a UK visa application *is* [grounds for refusal](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal), and if discovered would undoubtedly result in it.